# Linked List implement method that removes the node before (after) the node having the given node value

Tags: c#, linked-list

This is my method to simply remove the node indicated, but how can I implement the DeleteBefore() and DeleteAfter() method that removes the node before (after) the node having the given node value.

```
public void DeleteAFter(T nodeVal)
    {
        Node<T> curr = front;
        Node<T> prev = null;
        // becomes true if we locate target
        bool foundItem = false;
        // scan until locate nodeVal or 
        // come to end of list
        while (curr != null && !foundItem)
        {
            // have a match 
            if (curr.NodeValue.Equals(nodeVal))
            {
                // remove the first node
                if (prev == null)
                {
                    front = front.Next;
                }
                // erase intermediate node
                else
                {
                    prev.Next = curr.Next;
                }
                foundItem = true;

            }
            else
            {
                // advanced curr and prev
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.Next;
            }
```

Comment: What stops you doing the equivalent of `DeleteAfter(node.prev)`?  or `DeleteAfter(node.next)`?

Comment: There is no point in writing an O(n) algorithm to remove an element from a collection.  Use List<> instead.